# Highlight the text according to text in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, highlight, angular7

customers.json file
[json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLl47.png)

customer.service.ts

[service.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPtMM.png)

userdetails.component.ts

[userdeatils.component.ts 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBbj1.png)
[userdetails.component.ts 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAB2d.png)

userdetails.component.html
[html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kaqdw.png)

so please I just Want to compare the goodword and badwords array with the json file of sentence data and find the goodwords and badwords in the sentence and highlight the word according if it is goodword then it highlight with green background and badword with red background.

Comment: Please add code sample of what have you tried so far.

Comment: Please do not post the code as links, share whatever you have tried so far and reproduce the issue if possible (use stackblitz for angular).

Comment: I am just trying by this method: for (var i = 0; i < this.goodwords.length; i++) {
      var re = RegExp(
          "\\b" + this.goodwords[i].replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&") + "\\b",
          "g"
        );
      this.k = this.k.replace(
        re,
        "<mark id='mark2'>" + this.goodwords[i] + "</mark>")
    }

Comment: @Tushar is a new contributor. Suggest him how he can ask a question. Stack Overflow is not just for SMART people. We should welcome every newbie here. So help him by suggesting him instead of making him demotivate by making negative feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of so much negative feedback on this question, I am here to give you an answer.

**Stackblitz** [**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kurwmd) **here**

> **Component**

Remember to make all the words in lowercase in the `goodWords` and the `badWords` array

```
 obj = {
    customer: [
      {
        threshold: 80,
        sentence: 'Agent : Thank you for calling ABC company. My name is Ashley. How may I help you today?'
      },
      {
        threshold: 40,
        sentence: 'Customer : I am calling because I recieved a wrong bill. I just paid my phone bill two days ago.'
      },
    ]
  };
  goodWords = ['thank', 'you', 'help', 'sorry', 'please'];
  badWords = ['wrong', 'our', 'last', 'my'];
```

> **HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of obj.customer">
    <span *ngFor="let word of item.sentence.split(' ')">

    <span *ngIf="goodWords && goodWords.indexOf(word.trim().toLowerCase()) > -1; else redWord">
      &nbsp;<span style="color: green">{{word}}</span>
    </span>

    <ng-template #redWord>      
      <span *ngIf="badWords && badWords.indexOf(word.trim().toLowerCase()) > -1; else other" style="color: red">
        {{word}}
      </span>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #other>
      {{word}}
    </ng-template>
  </span>
   <br><br>
</div>
```

So I have handled all the things in the `HTML` itself. Hopefully, this will work for you.

Comment: Can you please Help regarding indexof line which gives me respective output but it gives error on console that Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] which affect my hole app.so can you suggest me without writing that indexof line in html file can we write that line in ts file.If you have solution on that please provide to me thank you

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please see. I have changed both *ngIf condition.